# What does 'conflictType: 5' mean in Flashbots getConflictingBundle?

Tags: javascript, ethers.js

Hi, I'm stuck trying to figure out what the conflict is with my bundle, im using:
`getConflictingBundle`

And I get this answer:
`{ initialSimulation: { bundleGasPrice: '41031065837', bundleHash: '0xf25eaeb1a54b96cc6214a83f4e828209068ae0f83a99ffa33d7ed59c2dca24f7', coinbaseDiff: '16674245565912306', ethSentToCoinbase: '0', gasFees: '16674245565912306', results: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ], stateBlockNumber: 17365166, totalGasUsed: 406381, firstRevert: undefined }, conflictType: 5, conflictingBundle: [], targetBundleGasPricing: { gasUsed: 406381, gasFeesPaidBySearcher: '38374796447176465', priorityFeesReceivedByMiner: '16674245565912306', ethSentToCoinbase: '0', txCount: 3, effectiveGasPriceToSearcher: '94430587176', effectivePriorityFeeToMiner: '41031065837' }, conflictingBundleGasPricing: undefined }`

Buy im not sure what is `conflictType: 5`.

Base on what i read in this function:

`export enum FlashbotsBundleConflictType { NoConflict, NonceCollision, Error, CoinbasePayment, GasUsed, NoBundlesInBlock }`
I think that the conflict is NoBundlesInBloc but i'm not sure what it means.

**Any help would be appreciated.**

I read the flashbots documentation and checked my submitted bundle.